# WCF Service Calls Javascript Code On Start After Removing the Code from the .ASPX Page

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, wcf

I have a C# .NET WCF project that consists of a JavaScript page that calls a service.  Upon start-up (in debug mode) it immediately calls the service, but I can not figure out why.  To attempt to troubleshoot the issue I have performed the standard things, such as cleaning and rebuilding.  I also have deleted the projects dll's under the Windows directory.  To further emphasize the point, I deleted all of the Javascript in the .aspx file, but it still appears to retain it.  I know this because the call stack is pulling the function call with the variables populated, even though they are not there.

What can cause this?  How should I go about clearing out the code, since it's no longer there?  I think it's a good place to start, as the other issue of calls at startup may be solved.

Comment: This is very unusual. A WCF service project does not have any web pages. When you debug it launches the WCF test client which allows you to call the services which do not have complex types.

It is also very unusual to use Javascript to call a WCF service, unless it's REST.

Comment: Microsoft supports using WCF with Ajax. What is the recommended way?  [Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410780%28v=vs.100%29) and an [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628467%28v=vs.100%29) about configuring an Ajax endpoint for WCF. @John Mc

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use the REST protocol anyway. This ensures that other non-ASP.net websites can consume your service (interoperability).

Is there any particular reason why you're using WCF for this? It would be easier to use MVC 4.0 with the REST API. WCF is more suited to heavy lifting with Data contracts etc but it is not very interoperable.

In response to your question, what is the VS project configured to use as a start item?

Comment: WCF was chosen since I had a prototype program that worked in this format and appeared stable.  I only found otherwise after the new program was pretty much finished that it was unstable.  The code  works fine during testing, when I an occasional clean start.

The start item is the .aspx file, which is the reason it skips the test client most of the time.    @John Mc